# iconv всегда EILSEQ

Tags: c++, linux

```
std::string decode_to_ascii(char* input, const size_t& input_len)
{
    iconv_t cb = iconv_open("ASCII//IGNORE", "UTF-8");

    if (cb == (iconv_t)(-1))
    {
        return "";
    }

    char* out = new char[input_len];

    size_t in_l = input_len;
    size_t out_l = input_len;

    size_t cvtlen = iconv(cb, &input, &in_l, &out, &out_l);

    if (cvtlen == (size_t)(-1))
    {
        auto err = errno;
        return "";
    }

    std::string result(out);

    iconv_close(cb);

    return result;
}
```

iconv всегда выдает ошибку EILSEQ с указанием на последний символ, что не так?

входной буфер гарантированно имеет кодировку УТФ-8, строка корректно кодируется другими средствами и корректно отображается в текстовом редакторе, если её сохранить в файл.

//IGNORE или //TRANSLIT не дают эффекта, пробовал совать туда 1 двухбайтовый символ, эффекта нет

Замечено, что на одних и тех же входных данных iconv выдает различный результат...

Comment: [Iconv: EILSEQ with ASCII//IGNORE but not with ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249628/iconv-eilseq-with-ascii-ignore-but-not-with-ascii-translit-ignore) На самом деле такое преобразование в ASCII можно тривиально сделать самому, отбрасывая байты с выставленным старшим битом.

Comment: @VTT, так суть в том, что в выходном буфере невалидные символы

Comment: `EILSEQ` - невалидные символы во входном буфере. Но в данном случае этот флаг будет выставлен потому что некторые из входных символов были отброшены.

Comment: входной буфер корректен

Comment: В ASCII можно представить только 7-битные символы. Т.е. если у вас корректные русские буквы   в UTF-8, то они все равно не могут быть переведены в ASCII

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка `EILSEQ` означает невалидные символы во входном буфере, однако при использовании с `"ASCII//IGNORE"` эта ошибка будет возвращаться в случае, если некоторые символы были отброшены. При этом указатель на входную строку будет указывать на проблемный байт - сразу за пределом входной строки. Таким образом, можно разделить ситуации, когда невалидная последовательность реально была во входной строке, и когда какие-то символы были отброшены. Также не следует передавать оригинальный указатель на выходной буфер (после вызовы функции он будет указывать на байт сразу после записанных) и не следует передавать оригинальный указатель на выходной буфер в функции, ожидающие заканчивающуюся нулем строку:

```
char * p_in{input};
size_t out_l{input_len};
char * p_out{out};
size_t out_l{input_len};
errno = 0;
size_t const cvtlen{iconv(cb, &p_in, &in_l, &p_out, &out_l)};
if (cvtlen == (size_t)(-1))
{
    auto const err{errno};
    if((EILSEQ != errno) || (p_in != (input + input_len)))
    {
        return "";
    } 
}
std::string result(out, static_cast<::std::size_t>(p_out - out));
```

Comment: я это понимаю, как мне сделать, чтобы валидные символы появились в выходном буфере?)

Comment: А они будут в выходном буфере. Заметьте, что этот буфер не обязятельно оканчивается нулем. И не стоит передавать в `iconv` указатель на исходный указатель. В вашем коде после выполнения функции `out` указывает на место сразу после записаных символов, не говоря уж о том, что память течет и исключения не обрабатываются.

Comment: боже, это самое неинтуитивное апи из всех

Comment: @goldstar_labs Тут хотя бы функции и параметры по-человечески называются. А вот, например, вызов `kill` чтобы послать сигнал - это да, ни разу не интуитивно.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что для iconv единственным способом определения размера выходной строки является `p_out - out` ?

Comment: @goldstar_labs По ходу дела да.